# enqueue plain JavaScript file from php plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have attempted with the below but it crashed the system.

```
<?php

    wp_register_script( 'support', 'js/big-support.js', );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'support' );

/* */
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, enable debugging when developing in WordPress.

```
// wp-config.php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

That will help you find the cause of errors.

Probably this line is the problem. older versions of php do not allow for trailing `,`'s in function calls

```
wp_register_script( 'support', 'js/big-support.js', );
                                               // ^  remove comma
```

Secondly, you should use the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook when registering scripts like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'SO_53028038_register_scripts');
function SO_53028038_register_scripts(){
     wp_enqueue_script('support', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/big-support.js';          
}
```